# Constant term in Fixedeffectmodels.jl

Tags: julia, regression

I was checking FixedEffectModels.jl package and I realized that in their [solution method](https://github.com/FixedEffects/FixedEffectModels.jl#solution-method) they don't have an intercept for their regression model. So for a one regressor model, they run `y = x + e` instead of `y = a + x + e`. I included a constant term in the formula, but the reported coefficient associated with the constant term is zero and other statistics (like Std. Error, t value, etc) are `NaN`.
Does FixedEffectsModel.jl automatically add a constant term to the formula. If not, how can I do that?

Comment: While I have not been using that particular package, you can always add to `x` a column of ones (`1`) and have exactly the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I did as I said in the post (I included a constant term in the formula). But the resulting coefficient is zero and all statistics are NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Julia or `FixedEffectsModels` question I'd say - I think you have a misunderstanding as to what a fixed effect model does.

See e.g. this answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/435865/149657 on Cross Validated.

In short, you are including a constant for each individual in your panel; you can think of these as one dummy variable per individual, with each dummy taking the value of one for an observation of the relevant individual. If you were to add all the individual dummy variables up, they would be a column of all ones - exactly collinear with the intercept. The intercept therefore can't be identified, leading to exactly the issues that you're seeing.

Have a look around on Cross Validated including the further links in the answer I linked above, and maybe read Chapters 13 and 14 of Wooldridge's Introductory Econometrics.